# How to determine and change a property type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Need help with this, I've tried some different solutions posted but no luck, I have a model for data:

```
public class ReceivingDataTableModel
{
    [Display(Name ="[[[Serial Number]]]")]
    public int DT_RowId { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to get result from a db but in this line:

```
var converted = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), property.Type);
```

Value is String and property.Type is Int (DT_RowId)

I get this error message:

> no coercion operator is defined between types system.String and
>   system.int32

Comment: Do you want to convert it from a int to a string? A simple `"" + DT_RowId` should to the trick.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing on that line is probably not at all what you want. Expression.Convert is used for **constructing type convertion operators at runtime**, as described in detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you need to convert something of type String to type Int32, you need to use the Int32.Parse method, as follows

```
Int32 value = Int32.Parse("2016");
```

Additional information of this method and a couple of others for more detailed conversion are described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx). Similar methods exist for Double (Double.Parse), Decimal (Decimal.Parse) and other primitive types.

**EDIT:**
If you want to be able to use it as a LINQ expersion, you can try the code used in this sample:

```
String value = "10";

var expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(typeof(Int32).GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(String) }), Expression.Constant(value)));

Int32 result = (Int32)expr.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

Comment: yes is not all, here is all the code   ` public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Compare<T>(ExpressionType operation, string propertyName, string value)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter((typeof(T)), "p");
            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
            var converted = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), property.Type)
            var body = Expression.MakeBinary(operation, property, converted);
        }`

Comment: Can you explain, what you want to achieve with that code? It looks a bit overcomplicated.

Comment: select from a database, and return a lambda expression to construct a json and render a dynamic table with select2 library

Comment: Why do you need an expression? Why not serialize the object directly into json?

Comment: i have a table and each column has a filter, there are many columns and many rows, so if i filter the column with name, it determines the column that should search, the system was working good, but now i need to add the column with the row id, and filter that column, but now i'm getting the error because of the datatype

Comment: I'm still not sure that I get your idea right, but I've updated the answer with an expression-based variant for this conversion. Please check if it helps.